# Equivalence liminf limsup lim

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sequence of non-negative real functions of $M$,  $f_n: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\{f_n(M)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Suppose we know that $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} (\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M))=0$.

Does this imply $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M))=0$? My attempt is:

> (1) $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M) \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow
> > \infty} f_n(M)$
>
> (2) Take $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}$ of both sides
>
> $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M) \leq
>  \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M)=0$
>
> (3) Since $f_n(M)\geq 0$ by assumption, we should have
>    $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M)\geq
>  0$
>
> (4) Combining (2) and (3) we conclude that $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}
> \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(M)=0$
>
> (5) since $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f_n(M)=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f_n(M)$ then $\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f_n(M)=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f_n(M)=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f_n(M)=0$

Is it correct?